# Does a GPU-Based video converter exist beyond Badaboom and Avivo?

Tags: video, gpu, video-conversion, gpgpu

I've been looking for one for a long time and I've found Badaboom to be incredibly bad and Avivo not to be able to run on my GPU (I have an nVidia GPU).

Does anybody know of any other solutions?

Comment: Good luck -- it looks like the CUDA encoders don't seem to have good quality yet (right now), but some might be using DXVA to accelerate the decoding of the source video.  What are your source/target formats?

Comment: Any, really. I'm just looking for a fast solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an interesting solution: [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com).

It looks like it supports GPU, and I'm currently converting a 2 hours long video (1.36GB). It got to 50% in 10 minutes. Going to share the results in a comment later.